# authorizing the url accessing a file under document root path in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, webserver

I am new to Apache web server.
I am trying to use media streaming in Apache 2.4 using 'h264_streaming_module modules'. I succeeded showing the stream in browser. I placed the mp4 file under DocumenRoot path and accessed it. 
The problem arises when I am trying to put the feature in my tomcat application. My intention is, when user clicks on the file in my application, url/request  should be first validated by server, to make sure he/she is coming from my application with valid session and not from some hacker. But now since I pass url with complete path to Apache web server, it streams to any one who uses that url.

Is there a way to perform the following:
1. To intercept the request by my application (say a servlet) before streaming  and redirect to Apache?
2. Is there a way to parse the request after it has hit the Apache and before streaming back?

Hope I could put my point correctly.

Comment: Typically one uses a router script for that.

Comment: can you please emphasis it

Comment: When the request comes to web server, that is redirected to a php script. This script will make a call to web application (say a servlet). The servlet validates the request and based the response from the servlet, php script either throw error message or streams the audio/video.

Comment: Yes, that is roughly the typical strategy. However the initial request is not "redirected", an http redirection works _externally_. Instead the request is internally "rewritten" and then processed by whatever logic you piont the rewriting to, be it a script or a servelet or whatever.